# Testing if a value is empty with variable.length

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I had a problem while coding a problem to calculate the area of a triangle given 3 sides,
when the inputs are empty i want my if to make a alert and my variables assume a given value,
but seems my programm just ignores the if:

```
function calcular(){
var lado1 = window.document.getElementById('lado1')
var lado2 = window.document.getElementById('lado2')
var lado3 = window.document.getElementById('lado3')
var l1 = Number(lado1.value)
var l2 = Number(lado2.value)
var l3 = Number(lado3.value)
if (lado1.length === 0 && lado2.length === 0 && lado3.length === 0) {
window.alert("Um ou mais campos vazios, considerando valores 5, 6 e 7.")
l1 = 5
l2 = 6
l3 = 7    
} 
var semp = (l1 + l2 + l3)/2
var area = Math.sqrt(semp*((semp-l1)*(semp-l2)*(semp-l3)))
answer.innerHTML = `A área do triângulo dado é de <strong>${area}</strong>!`
}
```

It works fine when i give any value on the inputs. Anyone can see the problem?

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem seems to be that you are using the AND operator (`&&`) instead of the OR operator (`||`), therefore it will only alert if **al** values are empty.

Your second problem is that you seem to be reading the `.length` of the DOM element itself, instead of the value.

You probably wanted to use this instead:

```js
if (lado1.value.length === 0 || lado2.value.length === 0 || lado3.value.length === 0) {
  window.alert("Um ou mais campos vazios, considerando valores 5, 6 e 7.")
  // ...  
}
```

or in short:

```js
if (!lado1.value || !lado2.value || !lado3.value) {
  window.alert("Um ou mais campos vazios, considerando valores 5, 6 e 7.")
  // ...  
}
```

Although you'd probably also want to check whether the input is a valid number anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong logical operator. && is only true if both sides are true. In your case you want the alert if one of the inputs is empty. So you need to use the or || operator

```
if (lado1.length === 0 || lado2.length === 0 || lado3.length === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the `if` statement is malformed. You should be using the OR operator (`||`), not AND (`&&`).